# How to fix error in client/server (reasked)

Tags: python

I want to pick a random element from my list so I use `random.sample(output, 1)` and then remove it, but first I transfer this element to a client process before deleting it. What I want to do is to make the client confirm if it wants said element and if it says no then don't delete it. I tried to implement this but I'm getting errors not when I run the server, but after I run the client process and it connects to the server. Really want to get this to work so help's appreciated!

Also the error given is not in the connection itself, it's in the transmission of data between them, in the threaded_client function on the server side, particularly while defining the stock variable. It says AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sample'

Server code:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import random

PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ThreadCount = 0
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
records = [('Empresa:', 'Altri', 'Cotação:', 5.37), ('Empresa:', 'BCP', 'Cotação:', 0.13),
           ('Empresa:', 'Corticeira Amorim', 'Cotação:', 10.58), ('Empresa:', 'CTT', 'Cotação:', 5.12),
           ('Empresa:', 'EDP Renováveis', 'Cotação:', 20.64),
           ('Empresa:', 'EDP', 'Cotação:', 4.67), ('Empresa:', 'Galp', 'Cotação:', 8.70),
           ('Empresa:', 'Ibersol', 'Cotação:', 5.82), ('Empresa:', 'Jerónimo Martins', 'Cotação:', 16.83),
           ('Empresa:', 'Mota-Engil', 'Cotação:', 1.35),
           ('Empresa:', 'NOS', 'Cotação:', 3.03), ('Empresa:', 'Novabase', 'Cotação:', 4.60),
           ('Empresa:', 'PHAROL', 'Cotação:', 0.11), ('Empresa:', 'REN', 'Cotação:', 2.37),
           ('Empresa:', 'Semapa', 'Cotação:', 11.50), ('Empresa:', 'Sonae', 'Cotação:', 0.80),
           ('Empresa:', 'Sonac', 'Cotação:', 0.77), ('Empresa:', 'The Navigator Company', 'Cotação:', 2.96)]


def create_random_numbs(input_list):
    output_numbers = []
    for given_number in input_list:
        max = given_number * 1.25
        min = given_number * 0.75
        random_number = random.random()
        random_number_in_desired_range = min + (random_number * (max - min))
        output_numbers.append(random_number_in_desired_range)
    return output_numbers


def swap():
    input_numbers = [x[-1] for x in records]
    new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)
    new_records = []
    for item, new_number in zip(records, new_numbers_in_desired_range):
        item_as_list = list(item)
        item_as_list[-1] = new_number
        new_records.append(tuple(item_as_list))
    return new_records


output = swap()
swap()

try:
    tcp.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("A aguardar ligação")
tcp.listen(10)
PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ThreadCount = 0
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    tcp.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("Awaiting conn")
tcp.listen(10)

def threaded_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Bem vindo à bolsa'))
    stock = random.sample(output, 1)
    order = str(stock)
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            break
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        tcp.send(str.encode(('Do you want this stock?' + order)))
        reply = connection.recv(2048)
        print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
        if (reply == 'Y'):
            tcp.send(str.encode(order))
            output.remove(order)
        elif (reply == 'N'):
            break
        else:
            tcp.send(str.encode('Insert valid letter'))

    connection.close()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

Client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket. SOCK_STREAM)
PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
compras = []

print('Awaiting conn')
try:
    Client.connect(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = Client.recv(1024)
while True:
    Client.send(str.encode('I wanna trade!'))
    Response = Client.recv(1024)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))
    Check = input('Y/N: ')
    Client.send(str.encode(Check))
    final = Client.recv(1024)
    compras.append(final.decode('utf-8'))
Client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing us part of your code, so we can't do very much.  I'm guessing you have `from random import random`, and that's what's causing your AttributeError.  That imports the random function, not the random module.  You need `import random`.

Given that error, none of your server code has ever run.  You have `encode` misspelled as `enconde`.  You are grabbing your sample from `output`. but you are removing it from `records`.

As you can imagine, this is not a good way to do a client/server setup.  You don't want to repeatedly exchange stuff back and forth.

Comment: Fixed all those errors and edited the code in accordance! I'm importing random and then from random import random since I need this for another bit of my code, if I post it all here it will get kind of bulky and I know it has no issues so that's why I didn't. However, the error I got after fixing all these is still     `stock = random.sample(output, 1)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sample'`

Comment: That's because you're doing `from random import random`.  Either that, or you have a global variable that is hiding the name `random`.  You haven't given us enough of the source to tell.

Comment: also not sure how I could do this another way since I need the client to say if it wants to receive the stock and then have the server send it and delete its record of it

Comment: alright I'll add the rest of the code but like I said I need from random import random for another part of my code

Comment: No, you do not.  You need to change that "other part of your code" to call `random.random` instead of `random`.

Comment: I wasn't aware, alright I changed my code and it fixed that issue like you said, but now I'm getting another error `tcp.send(str.encode(('Do you want this stock?' + stock)))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Comment: The key is, you don't do "conversations" like this with a client/server.  The conversation is between the client and the user.  A real system wouldn't have a server offer a random stock like this.  The client would ask the server what's available, and then send a message saying what the user wanted.  Those should be machine-to-machine exchanges, not user-to-machine exchanges.

Comment: Are you doing any debugging at all here to chase your own problems?  `random.sample` returns a list of one item.  You need `stock[0]`.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing str(stock) since it said I had to concatenate a string but I got an error anyways

Comment: I changed all the encoded messages to + stock[0] but it still gave the same concatenate a string error

Comment: the error I got after turning stock into a string was different though, it was `OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied` which is weird because the client and server are connected and I know this from a while loop at the end of my code which prints in the terminal after the connection is established the ip and port of client, and it's still being printed

Comment: You're still not doing debug prints to learn what you have.  `stock[0]` is going to be an entry in `records`, which is a tuple.  The stock symbols is going to be `stock[0][1]`, right?

Comment: Sorry not quite sure I'm following, when I `print(stock)` and `print(stock[0])` it prints a random element from my list, the complete element, for example `[('Empresa:', 'Novabase', 'Cotação:', 4.354002669763114)]`, the difference being that the second way prints this before the error and the way I had it prints it afterwards. `print(stock[0][1])` only prints the 2nd element, the company name which in this case would be "Novabase"