# Problems in communication between server and client

Tags: python

I want to pick a random element from my list so I use `random.sample(output, 1)` and then remove it, but first I transfer this element to a client process before deleting it. What I want to do is to make the client confirm if it wants said element and if it says no then don't delete it. I tried to implement this but I'm getting errors not when I run the server, but after I run the client process and it connects to the server. Really want to get this to work so help's appreciated!

Also the error given is `OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied`

Server code:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import random

PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ThreadCount = 0
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
records = [('Empresa:', 'Altri', 'Cotação:', 5.37), ('Empresa:', 'BCP', 'Cotação:', 0.13),
           ('Empresa:', 'Corticeira Amorim', 'Cotação:', 10.58), ('Empresa:', 'CTT', 'Cotação:', 5.12),
           ('Empresa:', 'EDP Renováveis', 'Cotação:', 20.64),
           ('Empresa:', 'EDP', 'Cotação:', 4.67), ('Empresa:', 'Galp', 'Cotação:', 8.70),
           ('Empresa:', 'Ibersol', 'Cotação:', 5.82), ('Empresa:', 'Jerónimo Martins', 'Cotação:', 16.83),
           ('Empresa:', 'Mota-Engil', 'Cotação:', 1.35),
           ('Empresa:', 'NOS', 'Cotação:', 3.03), ('Empresa:', 'Novabase', 'Cotação:', 4.60),
           ('Empresa:', 'PHAROL', 'Cotação:', 0.11), ('Empresa:', 'REN', 'Cotação:', 2.37),
           ('Empresa:', 'Semapa', 'Cotação:', 11.50), ('Empresa:', 'Sonae', 'Cotação:', 0.80),
           ('Empresa:', 'Sonac', 'Cotação:', 0.77), ('Empresa:', 'The Navigator Company', 'Cotação:', 2.96)]


def create_random_numbs(input_list):
    output_numbers = []
    for given_number in input_list:
        max = given_number * 1.25
        min = given_number * 0.75
        random_number = random.random()
        random_number_in_desired_range = min + (random_number * (max - min))
        output_numbers.append(random_number_in_desired_range)
    return output_numbers


def swap():
    input_numbers = [x[-1] for x in records]
    new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)
    new_records = []
    for item, new_number in zip(records, new_numbers_in_desired_range):
        item_as_list = list(item)
        item_as_list[-1] = new_number
        new_records.append(tuple(item_as_list))
    return new_records


output = swap()
swap()

try:
    tcp.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("A aguardar ligação")
tcp.listen(10)
PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ThreadCount = 0
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    tcp.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("Awaiting conn")
tcp.listen(10)

def threaded_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Bem vindo à bolsa'))
    stock = random.sample(output, 1)
    order = str(stock)
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            break
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        tcp.send(str.encode(('Do you want this stock?' + order)))
        reply = connection.recv(2048)
        print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
        if (reply == 'Y'):
            tcp.send(str.encode(order))
            output.remove(order)
        elif (reply == 'N'):
            break
        else:
            tcp.send(str.encode('Insert valid letter'))

    connection.close()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

Client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket. SOCK_STREAM)
PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
compras = []

print('Awaiting conn')
try:
    Client.connect(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = Client.recv(1024)
while True:
    Client.send(str.encode('I wanna trade!'))
    Response = Client.recv(1024)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))
    Check = input('Y/N: ')
    Client.send(str.encode(Check))
    final = Client.recv(1024)
    compras.append(final.decode('utf-8'))
Client.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401627/how-to-fix-error-in-client-server-reasked. Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: I tried to delete it but I can't

Comment: Then don't try to delete it. You're clearly on the edge of a question ban for a series of closed and downvoted questions. Doing things like deleting questions that people have tried to answer is going to make it worse. You may just have to be patient and wait for an answer on your old questions

Comment: You can always edit your question to clarify or expand if that is all you need.

Comment: I'm sorry then, I won't repost again, it's just I really need to fix this and everything I've tried I just keep getting errors, in the communication part